# Add elements of array to each column of matrix using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix 3x3 and array with 3 values and I want to add each value of my array to each column of the matrix, so for example, if I have matrix like:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9]]
```

and array `[1, 2, 3]`
I want to get a result like

```
[[2, 3, 4],
 [6, 7, 8],
 [10, 11, 12]]
```

But now when I'm trying to add my array to matrix it adds it by columns, so I get this:

```
[[2, 4, 6],
 [5, 7, 9],
 [8, 10, 12]]
```

And I can not change the axis to add operation or find method to do such calculation. Maybe I need to do it in a few steps? Or I just missed something?

Comment: By `broadcasting` rules, to add (m,) shape to a (m,n), you need to reshape the 1d array to (m,1).  Changing (m,) to (1,m) is automatic, but no the other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `transpose`:

```
>>> arr1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                    [4, 5, 6],
                    [7, 8, 9]])
>>> arr2 = np.array([1, 2, 3])

>>> (arr1.T + arr2).T
array([[ 2,  3,  4],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

Or make `arr2` a column matrix by expanding dimension:

```
>>> arr1 + arr2[:,None]
array([[ 2,  3,  4],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [10, 11, 12]])
```

If both are `list`s:

```
>>> arr1 = [[1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6],
            [7, 8, 9]]
>>> arr2 = [1, 2, 3]
np.add(arr1, np.expand_dims(arr2, 1))
```

References:

1. Transpose: [`np.ndarray.T`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html)
2. Expand dimensions: [`np.expand_dims`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html)
3. [`np.add`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.add.html)

Answer (score 1):

an elegant solution would be

```
A

>>>  [[1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6],
      [7, 8, 9]]
```

```
B

>>>  [1, 2, 3]
```

```
ans = A + B[:, None]
ans

>>> [[ 2,  3,  4],
     [ 6,  7,  8],
     [10, 11, 12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `numpy.newaxis` operator, as shown in `Code 1`(explained in a grate book - [Python Data Science Handbook by Jake VanderPlas](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.05-computation-on-arrays-broadcasting.html)) to achieve the desired result:

**Code 1:**

```
import numpy as np


A = np.array(
    [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]
)
x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
A + x[np.newaxis:]
```

**Output:**

```
Out:
array([[ 2,  4,  6],
       [ 5,  7,  9],
       [ 8, 10, 12]])
```

It also will be the most efficient way to accomplish this task in terms of speed and memory consumption, if you are dealing with numerical data in large datasets, because `numpy` is much more efficient than `python.list` object, due to `numpy`s' type awareness.

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

one way to do it would be the following.

```
array1 = [[1, 2, 3],
         [4, 5, 6],
         [7, 8, 9]]

array2 = [1, 2, 3]

for i in range(0, len(array2)):
    for j in range(0, len(array1[i-1])):
        array1[i][j] += array2[i]


print(array1)
```